# Calculating a correlation matrix with pspearman package with apply() function

Tags: r, apply, correlation, sapply, mapply

I am trying to calculate the Spearman correlation and p-value for a data frame. For better p-value approxiamation, I must stick to the pspearman package. I am expecting a result similar with the `rcorr()` function. But I have a problem when performing `pspearman:spearman.test()` row by row.

My dataframe contains 5000 rows (genes), and 200 columns(spots). And I want to get a correlation matrix and p-value matrix for these 5000*5000 gene-gene pairs. The correlation is only calculated when both two genes are not NAs in more than two spots.

I can achieve this with loops but it is too slow for my big dataset. I have problems when I try to use `apply(),sapply(),mapply()` to improve the speed.

This is what I've tried:

```
data = data.frame(matrix(rbinom(10*100000, 50, .5), ncol=200))
dim(data) #5000, 200
rownames(data) <- paste("gene", 1:5000, sep="") 
colnames(data) <- paste("spot",1:200,sep='')

library(pspearman)
spearFunc = function(x,y=data) {
  df = rbind(x,y)
  # Check the number of complete spots.There are no NAs in this set.
  complete = sum(!(is.na(x)) & !(is.na(y)))
  if (complete >=2 ) {
    pspearman::spearman.test(as.numeric(x),as.numeric(y))
    # This function returns a list containing 8 values, like pvalue,correlation
    }}

pair.all1 = mapply(spearFunc,data,data)
dim(pair.all1)
# 8 200, 200 is the number of columns 
pair.all2 = apply(data,1,spearFunc)
```

Which results in error:

> Error in pspearman::spearman.test(as.numeric(x), as.numeric(y)) : 
>   (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

I hope to use spearman.test for every gene pair with apply() to do

```
spearman.test(data[gene1],data[gene1]) 
spearman.test(data[gene1],data[gene2])
....
spearman.test(data[gene1],data[gene5000])
...
spearman.test(data[gene5000],data[gene5000])
```

It should return a dataframe of 8 rows and 25,000,000 columns(5000*5000 gene pairs).

Is it possible to use apply() inside apply() to achieve my purpose?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider creating pair-wise combinations of genes from `row.names` with `combn` and then iterating through the list of pairs through a defined function. Be sure to return an `NA` structure from `if` logic to avoid `NULL` in matrix output.

However, be forewarned that pair-wise permutations of 5,000 genes (`choose(5000, 2)`) results very high at 12,497,500 elements! Hence, `sapply` (a loop itself) may not be that different in performance than `for`. Look into parallelizing the iteration.

```
gene_combns <- combn(row.names(data), 2, simplify = FALSE)

spear_func <- function(x) {
  # EXTRACT ROWS BY ROW NAMES  
  row1 <- as.numeric(data[x[1],])
  row2 <- as.numeric(data[x[2],]) 

  # Check the number of complete spots.There are no NAs in this set.
  complete = sum(!(is.na(x)) & !(is.na(y)))

  if (complete >=2 ) {
    pspearman::spearman.test(row1, row2)        
  } else {
    c(statistic=NA, parameter=NA, p.value=NA, estimate=NA, 
      null.value=NA, alternative=NA,   method=NA, data.name=NA)
  }
}

pair.all2 <- sapply(gene_combns, spear_func)
```

---

**Testing**

Above has been tested with `cor.test` (exactly same input args and output list as [spearman.test](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pspearman/versions/0.1-10/topics/spearman.test) but more accurate `p-value`) using a small sample of dataset (50 obs, 20 vars):

```
set.seed(82418)
data <- data.frame(matrix(rbinom(10*100000, 50, .5), ncol=200))[1:50, 1:20]
rownames(data) <- paste0("gene", 1:50) 
colnames(data) <- paste0("spot", 1:20)

gene_combns <- combn(row.names(data), 2, simplify = FALSE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "gene1" "gene2"    
# [[2]]
# [1] "gene1" "gene3"    
# [[3]]
# [1] "gene1" "gene4"    
# [[4]]
# [1] "gene1" "gene5"    
# [[5]]
# [1] "gene1" "gene6"    
# [[6]]
# [1] "gene1" "gene7"

test <- sapply(gene_combns, spear_func)  # SAME FUNC BUT WITH cor.test
test[,1:5]

#             [,1]                              [,2]                             
# statistic   885.1386                          1659.598                         
# parameter   NULL                              NULL                             
# p.value     0.1494607                         0.2921304                        
# estimate    0.3344823                         -0.2478179                       
# null.value  0                                 0                                
# alternative "two.sided"                       "two.sided"                      
# method      "Spearman's rank correlation rho" "Spearman's rank correlation rho"
# data.name   "row1 and row2"                   "row1 and row2"                  
#             [,3]                              [,4]                             
# statistic   1554.533                          1212.988                         
# parameter   NULL                              NULL                             
# p.value     0.4767667                         0.7122505                        
# estimate    -0.1688217                        0.08797877                       
# null.value  0                                 0                                
# alternative "two.sided"                       "two.sided"                      
# method      "Spearman's rank correlation rho" "Spearman's rank correlation rho"
# data.name   "row1 and row2"                   "row1 and row2"                  
#             [,5]                             
# statistic   1421.707                         
# parameter   NULL                             
# p.value     0.7726922                        
# estimate    -0.06895299                      
# null.value  0                                
# alternative "two.sided"                      
# method      "Spearman's rank correlation rho"
# data.name   "row1 and row2"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your  patience. The combn() function and trying to avoid NULL are so helpful. I used spearman.test to calculate p value, because the p-value accuracy of cor.test() depends on the null distribution of data and statistical ties. Although it's called "accurate" but it is not possible to calculate a real p value when n>22. It is better to use approximations when n>22, like what the spearman.test function does. It reduces false positive rate greatly. (ref: Fast computation of the exact null distribution of Spearman's and Page's L statistic for samples with and without ties)

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Thanks for the info, too -TIL.Happy coding!